# Single NodeManager for Multiple AdminServers

Tags: weblogic12c

I have installed Oracle Unified Directory 12.2.1.4 with NodeManager and an AdminServer.
On the same machine, in a different domain, I have installed Oracle Access Manager 12.2.1.4 with NodeManager, AdminServer and ManagedServer.

I believe I should have skipped the NodeManager installation on OAM and configured the OUD NodeManager to manage the OAM servers.

Does this sound correct?
Does it matter whether OUD NM manages OAM servers
or should OAM NM manage OUD servers?

Is what I am thinking even possible?  I assume it is but I am still learning stuff.

Comment: It is possible to handle several managed servers from several domains with only one nodemanager instance (per-host nodemanager)
The recommanded way in 12c is to use a "per-domain" node manager. In this situation, each domain runs its own node manager (listening to a unique port) on each host.